# Google Contacts API contact's URL list retrieval in .net

Tags: vb.net, api, contacts

I'm trying to sync my local contacts (CRM written in vb.net) with Google Contacts with the help of the Google API. All went swell until I tried to retrieve/update the URL list for every contact downloaded from the Google servers. How do you do that? I mean it's easy for the emails, IM addresses, phone numbers etc because each one of the contact objects has a Emails, PostalAddresses, etc collection but it seems there is none for the URLs. This is how I parse the postal addresses list:

```
If contact.PostalAddresses.Count > 0 Then
 For Each address As StructuredPostalAddress In contact.PostalAddresses
  ' Do something with the address
 Next
End If
```

For the URLs it should be something like this:

```
If contact.?URLs?.Count > 0 Then
 For Each url As ?URL? In contact.?URLs?
  ' Do something with the URL
 Next
End If
```

But there is no URLs or Links collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
If contact.ContactEntry.Websites.Count > 0 Then
  For Each URL As ContactsLink In contact.ContactEntry.Websites                                  
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(URL.Href + vbCrLf)
  Next 
End If
```

Comment: I've already provided the answer above. The collection's name is Websites